# Missing all endorsements, ithacanet

Tags: node

I had posted this question on slack (tezos-baking#application-support) but the feedback stopped.  Haven't been able to find answers on slack, reddit or stack exchange that fit my scenario. Have a node and baker running on a vps, ithacanet  Activated account on April 2, then rights began a few days after that, but since then I missed all endorsements and baking chances.  I'm sure part of the problem was that I had not properly set up the signer. I "believe" I have that set up correctly now, and reactivated the account today (had been deactivated after missing the endorsements for awhile). But still missing all endorsements. Baker account number is tz1fh2hMTTQKYejt4F4wCxyQAD1VenCpMEg3. After reactivating the account today, reran

tezos-client import secret key omaha tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/tz1.......
tezos-client sign bytes 0x00 for omaha

then restarted the tezos-node and the baker.  Running baker in debug mode, and there are no errors. Also, no logging about injecting endorsements.  Don't know if it's still a signing issue.  This is the signer running on another vps

tezos-signer launch socket signer -a xx.xx.xx.xx -p xxxxx

Not seeing any errors in the signer.  I set up the signer according to https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/key-management.html.  I didn't set it up with a ledger since I'm just using test tezos.

Following tezos.gitlab.io/introduction, these were the steps I took from the beginning

tezos-node identity generate

wget https://ithacanet.xtz-shots.io/ithacanet-361935.rolling

tezos-node config init --data-dir ~/tezos-ithacanet --network ithacanet

tezos-node snapshot --data-dir ~/tezos-ithacanet import --block BMMM6hr7ZiJeAaS6qKerPYbioFngp8ujLodovffaAVq6oE4VCBh ithacanet-361935.rolling

nohup tezos-node run --data-dir ~/tezos-ithacanet --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1 &

tezos-client activate account omaha with testtez-ithaca.json

tezos-client gen keys omaha

tezos-client register key omaha as delegate

nohup tezos-baker-012-Psithaca run with local node ~/tezos-ithacanet omaha &

Comment: #application-support is the wrong channel. You need to join #ithacanet and also post in #getting_started

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.  See the threads started on April 11 at slack.com, tezos-baking, # getting-started, by Andrew Best.  Particularly the thread started April 12 at 6:06pm between Andrew Best and Bake tz for Me.  For those who don't have a slack.com account, here's what happened: in following the steps to set up the node, baker and signer at https://tezos.gitlab.io/, I didn't use my little brain and when I ran `tezos-client import secret key omaha tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx/tz1VA....`, it had overlaid the address and keys of the omaha address I had first set up near the beginning with `tezos-client activate account omaha with testtez-ithaca.json` I removed both accounts using the tezos-client forget address command and reran the activation and secret import with different aliases. Now endorsing.